# Как выполнять математические действия?

Tags: java, android

В приложение есть 2 EditText мне нужно выполнить математическое действие 1EditText * 2EditText  и то что получится умножить на 2

```
binding.inputQuantity
binding.inputPrice
```

Нашел пример

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputQuantity.getText().toString());
int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputPrice.getText().toString());

int res = (a * b) * 2;
binding.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```

Но срабатывает оно когда у EditText изначально добавлен какой то текст  `android:text="1"` + к тому же при повторном вводе данных уже нечего не работает. Мне нужно что бы оно автоматом обновлялось при вводе в EditText без каких либо обработчиков нажатий.

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputQuantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_view"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
        android:text="1"
        android:hint="@string/_1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTitle"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="97dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_price"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
        android:text="1"
        android:hint="@string/_2"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="13dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputTitle"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="97dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />
```

Нашел реализацию того что мне нужно но только когда из какого либо поля EditText убрать значение то приложение закрывается из за того что поле пустое, как это можно исправить?

```
    binding.inputPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputQuantity.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputPrice.getText().toString());

        int res = (a * b) * 2;
        binding.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});

binding.inputQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputQuantity.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputPrice.getText().toString());

        int res = (a * b) * 2;
        binding.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(res));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Comment: получите текстовые значения обоих полей, конвертируйте оба значения в числовое представление, проведите операцию умножения, и.... то что получится умножить на 2

Comment: @JVic я привёл выше пример только если поля editText пустые приложения закрывается из за этого?

Answer (score 0):

Вот что помогло мне решить эту проблему, а именно исключения tey end catch!

```
private void gettingTotalPrice() {

    binding.inputPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputQuantity.getText().toString());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputPrice.getText().toString());

                int res = (a * b) * 2;
                binding.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(res));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    binding.inputQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputQuantity.getText().toString());
                int b = Integer.parseInt(binding.inputPrice.getText().toString());

                int res = (a * b) * 2;
                binding.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(res));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
}
```